# Pass data to swingWorker?

Tags: java, swingworker

Is there a way to pass data e.g an object to the swingWorker before invoking "swingWorker.execute"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I handle this by making the constructor of my SwingWorker require the needed objects.  That way the compiler will force me to remember to pass the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You should add an accessor to your SwingWorker extended class

---

`SWExtended swe = new SWExtended();

swe.setMethod(newObjectValue);

swe.execute();`